# Regression of y/x on x

Tags: regression

I have a simple question but I do not manage to be sure! I would be very grateful if you can confirm me!
Do we have the possibility to estimate the following model :
$$\frac{y}{x}= \alpha+\beta x+\varepsilon$$
Is there any problem because the endogeneous variable contains already the explanatory variable $x$?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Algebraically, there is no problem. Just define $z=(z_1,\ldots,z_n)$ with $z_t=y_t/x_t$. Regressing $z$ on an interecept and $x$ can be done by usual formulas.

Answer (score 0):

As yumero commented, there is no problem from an algebraic point of view.

However, from a regression point of view, this is problematic since what is measured is $y$ and not $\frac y x$. I would definitely suggest that you set the regression as $$y= \alpha x+\beta x^2+\varepsilon$$ which is just a multilinear regression without intercept.

For sure, if the errors are marginal, this will not make much difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot Claude and Yurnero